# Read-only-port 10255 on Kubernetes node didn`t exist

Tags: kubernetes, metricbeat

I have a problem, I need to collect metric data from read-only-port located on 10255, but unfortunately by using netstat I found that such port don't exists at all. Can somebody help with advise, how could I create such port on kubelet or how can I avoid this port for data collection?

Answer (score 1):

The *kubelet* requires a parameter to be set: **--read-only-port=10255** ([read more about kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/))

If you are using *kubeadm* to bootstrap the cluster, you can use a config file to pass in for the kubelet (look for how to ["Set Kubelet parameters via a config file"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/))

If, for example, you are using [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kubespray), there's the **kube_read_only_port** variable (commented out by default).

> Warning! This is not a good practice and the [read-only-port is deprecated](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/732). There are ways to read from the secure port but this is another story.

Comment: I tried to define read only port, but it says that port is deprecated. Do you know, how to get it working/available?

Comment: Which kubernetes version are you using?

Comment: 1.10.3 Kubernetes